# Why clearTimeout with millisec argument is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple banner rotator. The fact is, when it rotates without any buton pressed, works fine, but when I press some button to change the banner and clear the time, it doesn't work.

Looks like the time does not clear.

```
        var tempo = 5000;
        var elemento;
        var quantos;
        var atual;
        
        // Inicia
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            bannerRotator("#destaques");
        
        });
        
        
        // Funções do Banner
        
        
        function bannerRotator(element) {
            
            // Conta quantos banners existem:
            $('<ul class="buttons"></ul>').appendTo(element);
            i = 0;
            $(element).find(".banner").each(function() {
                $(element).find(".banner").eq(i).addClass("id"+i);
                buttons = element+" ul.buttons";
                acId = i+1;
                $('<li><a href="javascript:getBanner('+i+');">'+acId+'</a></li>').appendTo(buttons);
                i++;
            });
            
            // Inicia a rotacao
            elemento = element;
            quantos = i;
            rotate(i,-1);
        
        }
        
        function getBanner(r) {
            r = r-1;
            rotate(quantos, r);
        }
        
        
        function rotate(i, base) {
            
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            
            if (base<i-1) {
                base++;
                atual = base;
                setTimeout('rotate('+i+', '+base+');', tempo);
            }
            else {
                base = 0;
                atual = base;
                setTimeout('rotate('+i+', '+base+');', tempo);
            }
            
            // Faz os fades
            
            $(elemento).find(".banner").animate({opacity: 0,});
            $(elemento).find(".banner").eq(base).animate({opacity: 1,});
            
            // Arruma os botoes
            
            $(elemento).find("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
            $(elemento).find("ul.buttons li").eq(base).addClass("active");
            
        }
```

Comment: please change `href="javascript:getBanner('+i+');"` to `href="#" onclick="getBanner('+i+'); return false"`

Comment: I suggest you pass a function to `setTimeout` instead of a string.  `setTimeout(function(){rorate(i,base);}, tempo);`

Comment: @Rocket passing a function instead of a string fails in some versions of IE

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because you're using `clearTimeout()` incorrectly. Your code needs to resemble the following:

```
var x = setTimeout("doStuff();", tempo);
clearTimeout(x);
```

You are currently using `tempo` as the timeout handle, which is why it isn't working.

Comment: Correct; I was just keeping in form with his original post, in which a string was passed as the first arg.

Answer (score 4):

Use the return from `setTimeout` to pass it to the `clearTimeout` function :

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(callBack, 1000);
//then, later in the code
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `clearTimeout` you need to pass it the value returned from a call to `setTimeout`.

```
var timeout;
// ...
timeout = setTimeout('rotate('+i+', '+base+');', tempo);
// ...
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You clear the timeout with the result returned from setTimeout...

```
var x = setTimeout(functionPointer, 500);
clearTimeout(x);
```

Comment: This won't work.  You're trying to use `x` as a local variable and as the name of a function in an outer scope.

Comment: roflz.. ty to my bad use of place holder... the x in setTimeout is your function call.. edited my post

Answer (score 0):

When you call setTimeout it will return an identifier.  That is what needs passed to clearTimeout.

Answer (score -2):

you never set `tempo` as a timer! do:

```
tempo = setTimeout('rotate('+i+', '+base+');', timeOutTime);
```

Then set `timeOutTime` as the number of ms you want the timer to go to