# Javascript: unable to clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm trying to call a function after a short delay after a user stops typing, but `clearTimeout()` does not seem to be doing what I think. The following is inside an Angular JS controller.

```
$scope.typing = false;
$scope.delay = undefined;

//Triggered by ng-keydown...
$scope.startTyping = function() {
    $scope.typing = true;
            console.log('start1', $scope.delay); //6
    clearTimeout( $scope.delay );
            console.log('start2', $scope.delay); //6... NOT getting cleared!
}

//Triggered by ng-keyup...
$scope.stopTyping = function() {
    $scope.typing = false;
    $scope.delay = setTimeout( $scope.lookup, 1000);
}

$scope.lookup = function() {

    if ($scope.typing === true){
        return false;
    }
    console.log('lookup'); //This fires after every key!
```

I see `lookup` in the logs for every key, instead of after every delay. Why is this?

**Update**

After logging the value of `delay` it is clear that `clearTimeout()` is not reseting the timer and instead, multiple timers are getting set and each one is triggering the lookup function.

*For reference...*

For anyone else troubleshooting `clearTimeout()`, here are some similar questions that may solve your problem (but didn't solve mine):

[clearTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462948/cleartimeout-not-working)

[clearTimeout() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173419/cleartimeout-not-working)

[clearTimeout is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549298/cleartimeout-is-not-working)

[clearTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397117/cleartimeout-not-working)

Comment: Is it "lookupJobs" or just "lookup"?

Comment: can you please show how `$scope.lookupJobs` is defined? also, this line seems odd: `$scope.delay;`. That is not a valid command, either remove it or do something like `$scope.delay = undefined;`

Comment: `keydown` event happens after `keyup` event. Whereas you're trying to `cleatTimeout` an `undefined` variable.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry that was a copy/paste error.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan are you saying the `keydown` event is triggered *after* `keyup` when a key is pressed? Or on the subsequent key press?

Comment: Well those timer handles are just numbers; you should inject some `console.log()` calls to verify that the timer value set when you start the timer is the same one used to stop it.

Comment: @Chips_100 I initialized `$scope.delay` as you advised.

Comment: Could not reproduce (http://jsfiddle.net/TN6zA/), but I'm using DOM `keyup`/`keydown` listeners; the event mechanisms you're using (Angular?) may vary.

Comment: @apsillers Good point. Perhaps `ng-keyup` / `ng-keydown` dont't work quite the same.

Comment: @Pointy Can you clarify your last comment. I don't quite follow what you are advising me to log.

Comment: @SDP I'm advising you to log the value of `$scope.delay` after you call `setTimeout()` and *before* you try to use it with `clearTimeout()`.  That will confirm that the value of `$scope.delay` is (or is not) being corrupted somehow.

Comment: @Pointy I added `console.log($scope.delay);` after the `clearTimeout()` and it appears to be continuing. It should be 0 or undefined I think, but it's a an int like `6`.

Comment: @SDP that's what timer handles look like - they're just numbers, as if the browser simply keeps a "timer counter" somewhere internally.

Comment: Sorry, did you check my jsfiddle? could you give me some feedback please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/y52Q2/1/

**Controller**

```
app.controller('Main', function ($scope) {

    var delay;

    var lookup = function() {

        console.log($scope.input);
    };

    $scope.lookup = function() {

        clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(lookup, 1000);
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
    <input ng-model="input" ng-change="lookup()"/>
</div>
```

The problem with the up/down attemp is that `stopTyping` gets called more times than `startTyping`:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/5hFjY/1/

Comment: Is there a reason why you refactored it to user `ng-change()`? The code I posted here is a bit simplified, so it would take me some work to do it this way. I can do it, but it would help to understand what problem this is solving.

Comment: I refactored it to work off of `ng-change()` and it works now. But I would still love to understand why my original version didn't work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's related to this specific aspect, but my code is throwing errors in FireFox (PC or Mac). I've posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766636/angular-js-interpolation-error-in-firefox

Comment: I had faced that error too and the answers you've got are right, Chrome doesn't implement the standard js Date and supports more date string formats than Firefox. You should parse the string first or if you'll need more date calculation just try momentjs (it rocks).

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this : http://jsfiddle.net/TN6zA/2/

```
$scope = {};

    //on keydown...
    document.getElementById("foo").onkeydown = function() {    
        clearTimeout( $scope.delay );
        $scope.delay = setTimeout( $scope.lookup, 1000);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Someone is typing";
    }

    $scope.lookup = function() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Nobody is typing";
    }

    $scope.lookup();
```